# Comunicación por ip

Tags: java, android, tcpip, ip

Buenas,

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de mensajería en la que lo único que conozco de los usuarios es su ip publica.
Necesito saber como puedo implementar esa comunicación a través del envio de la información por IP.
No puedo utilizar ningún sevidor, ni Firebase...por ejemplo
Solo tengo que enviar y recibir mensajes a traves de la direccion ip publica de mi smartphone.

Para enviar el string(que es lo unico que necesito enviar) utilizo la siguiente funcion:

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitNetwork().build());
            String ip = "158.42.146.127";
            int puerto = 7;
            try {
                Socket sk = new Socket(ip, puerto);
                BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter salida = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()), true);
                salida.println(mensaje);
                sk.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

Pero necesito saber como puede estar la aplicación siempre a la espera de recibir mensajes.

Gracias.

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Echa un vistazo aquí, a ver si te ayuda.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904717/android-studio-socket-server-and-client-send-and-recieve-data
Un saludo.

Comment: Hasta donde yo se, los smartphones no tienen una ip pública (ver https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385669/2711585), por lo cual nunca podrías hacer eso que quieres hacer. Usar un servidor que haga de intermediario sería la única forma.

Comment: Buenas Mariano, esto realizando un PFG y la aplicación sería cliente-cliente. Cada dispoitivo necesita sincronizarse con el otro y por ello en la primera comunicación le envía su IP mediante SMS. Posteriormente cuando el dispositivo detecta que su IP ha cambiado informa al resto del cambio.

Comment: Por ello lo que necesito saber es como puedo establecer esa comunicacion TCP/IP en las dos partes y que tenga un proceso a la escucha de la llegada de mensajes de sus usuarios sincronzados.